# Me aparece nullreferenceException como lo puedo solucionar

Tags: c#

```
string codiuno, codidos, descrip, precio, descu, lugarorigen;
DataRow fila = miCastillitoDataSet1.Tables["MiCastillido"].Rows.Find(textBox1.Text);
if (fila == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("codigo 1 no se encuentra");
}
else
{
    codidos = fila.ItemArray[1].ToString();
    descrip = fila.ItemArray[2].ToString();
    precio = fila.ItemArray[3].ToString();
    descu = fila.ItemArray[4].ToString();
    lugarorigen = fila.ItemArray[5].ToString();
    MessageBox.Show("codiuno: " + textBox1.Text + "\nCodigo 2: " + codidos + "\nDescripcion: " + descrip +
                    "\n Precio: " + precio + "\nDescuento: " + descu + "\nlugarorigen: " + lugarorigen);
}
```

Comment: `nullreference`? Esto se parece más a C#

Comment: [Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Para que la comunidad entienda mejor su pregunta, debe leer [cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Luego editar la pregunta.